# Laravel many to many relation not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

this might be a silly question, but I am trying to connect 1 table to 2 related tables.
[image]

Inside the values array component_id 1 shows up when requesting data for component with id 2.

The relation inside Component::class

```
public function fields()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Field::class, FieldValue::class, 'component_id', 'id', 'id', 'field_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what your models are.  Component, Field, and FieldValue?  So a component hasMany Fields and a component hasMany field_values through field?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you make mistake, try determine relationships like that:

```php
public function fields()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Field::class, FieldValue::class);
}
```

OR

```php
public function fields()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Field::class, FieldValue::class, 'component_id', 'field_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

And of course, check correct your code reading official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) how to use this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Component::

```
public function fields()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}

public function values()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Field::class, FieldValue::class);
}
```

Field::  (table) *id,component_id*

```
public function component()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Component::class);
}
public function values()
{
   return $this->hasMany(FieldValue::class);
}
```

FieldValue:: (table)*id,field_id*

```
public function field()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Field::class);
}
```